# Составное переменное имя переменной bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Здравствуйте, коллеги.
Есть скрипт. Его часть:

```
NODE1IPV4=192.168.0.1
NODE2IPV4=192.168.0.2
NODENUM=1
```

Как мне вставить `$NODENUM` в имя переменной с ip? т.е. получить что-то вроде

```
[root@host]#echo "$NODE{$NODENUM}IPV4"
[root@host]#192.168.0.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

это называется двойная интерполяция

```
eval echo "\$NODE${NODENUM}IPV4"
```

Answer (score 1):

косвенная адресация неплохо описана в разделе [indirect references](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html) небезызвестного руководства [abs (advanced bash-scripting guide)](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html):

```
eval echo "\$NODE${NODENUM}IPV4"
```

---

но, на мой взгляд гораздо удобнее использовать ассоциативные массивы. сначала массив надо объявить:

```
$ declare -A ar
```

а затем использовать:

```
$ ar[1]=192.168.0.1
$ n=1; echo ${ar[$n]}
192.168.0.1
```

массив (при необходимости) может быть и многомерным:

```
$ ar[1,2,3]=192.168.0.10
$ x=1; y=2; z=3; echo ${ar[$x,$y,$z]}
192.168.0.10
```